# Spring boot access application.properties in components

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I want to add a property in application.properties of my spring boot application and be able to to access it and use it in one of my other classes, but I am getting null.

Here is my application.properties

```
server.port=8052
subscribe.period=5
```

My class that will access it

```
@Component
public class SubscriptionService {

    @Value("${subscribe.period}")
    private String period

    @Autowired
    public SubscriptionService(String period) {
        String time = period;
        ...
    }

}
```

But it seems period is not being populated, in fact null. It shows as nill when I run as maven build in eclipse at least, im thinking it might be trying to access it before the properties file is even load, if so how might i approach this?

Comment: are you importing the correct class for the annotation @Value? It should be org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value

Comment: I am not sure where it went wrong as the information is not suffiecient. Try autowiring `Environment` and then `environment.getRequiredProperty("subscribe.period")` just to make sure properies are loading

Comment: Thanks for your replies, it's possible that i am using the wrong @Value import but I'm unable to check at the moment as I just left the office but I'll check once I get home. I did try Autowiring environment but it shows up as a null object when i set a breakpoint there. However, I'm also autowiring my SubscriptionService as above in another component in my application, so I'm wondering if its possible that my other components are initialized first upon start up which can result in my build failing as the nested ordering of events are wrong.

Comment: However im certain that application.properties is in the right place as my embedded tomcat is binding to the correct port as specified by server.port

Comment: Well how do you expect it to work in this scenario? You are using an element before Spring has had time to touch it? If you want it to use you would need to put the `@Value` on the constructor-arg. I would actually expect that this would fail with component-scanning, stating that it cannot autowire the constructor...

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean Deinum, do you mean autowiring the component in another component may cause this?

Answer (score 1):

Deinum in the comments above is correct. I have no idea why as it differs from every other online example I have read so I would invite him to give an explanation.

I had to put the @Value in the argument of the constructor

```
@Component
public class SubscriptionService {

private String period

@Autowired
public SubscriptionService(@Value("${subscribe.period}") String period) {
    String time = period;
    ...
}
```

}

Then it works